# Receive multiple arguments after method call in dbus-cxx

Tags: c++, dbus

I use [dbus-cxx](http://dbus-cxx.sourceforge.net/) to do method calls via dbus. Now there are methods that return more than one argument and I couldn't figure out how to receive any arguments beside the first one.

I initialize the proxy method:

```
DBus::MethodProxy<int>& info_proxy = *(object->create_method<int>(ServerName, "Info"));
```

and when I grab the return value, it is only the first value of the three possible outputs in this case.

The XML describing the methods looks like this:

```
<method name="Info">
    <arg type="i" direction="out" name="rate"/>
    <arg type="i" direction="out" name="freq"/>
    <arg type="i" direction="out" name="nch"/>
</method>
```

Calling the method from within QDBusViewer delivers the output `Arguments: 1813099, 44100, 2` so it provides three outputs but I cannot figure out how to access these.

**EDIT:** I got it working, by using the tool dbus-cxx-xml2cpp I got a method definition that uses a `DBus::CallMessage` instead of a `DBus::MethodProxy`. The resulting reply contained all arguments the method returns.

Comment: Why not generate classes from XML with the code generator (`dbus-cxx-xml2cpp` tool)? But if you're doing by hand, I would expect to see something like that: `DBus::MethodProxy<void, int&, int&, int&>`.

Comment: I experienced some difficulties building the tool, thus I decided to do it by hand.
I had the function like you suggested before, but when I run the program I get `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::shared_ptr<DBus::Error>'` and I fail to find the problem.

Comment: If it's hard to build, then it makes sense to use a dbus wrapper that comes with the OS: it's probably `dbus-c++` (or find a packaged `dbus-cxx`). What is the build error? What is the error in the `DBu‌​s::Error` exception?

Comment: When I installed it from the AUR I also got the code generator. The generated method helped immensely, as the correct way is a CallMessage instead of a simple method call. The answer to this call is a stream which contains the 3 arguments.

Comment: You can post that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, by using the tool `dbus-cxx-xml2cpp` I got a method definition that uses a `DBus::CallMessage` instead of a `DBus::MethodProxy`. The resulting reply contained all arguments the method returns.